# In R, how can I find unique pairs of numbers across rows when there are three columns?

Tags: r, mesh

I am working with triangular meshes in R. For those not familiar, the PLY format has two main components, a 3 by n matrix of vertex x,y,z coordinates, where n is the number of vertices, and a 3 by m matrix of faces where each number references one line from the vertex matrix, and so defining three corners of a triangular face. I am trying to find the mesh boundary edges, which are the "sides" of the triangles that are only referenced once in the faces matrix.

Therefore my question is, how do I find unique pairs of numbers across rows where there are three columns?

```
face 1 4 6 7
face 2 7 6 8
face 3 9 11 12 
face 4 10 9 12
```

Here line (face) 1 has the edge 4-7 that only appears once, while 6-7 appears twice, as does 9-12.
unique() works across rows, but looks for unique rows, and expects the numbers to be in the same order. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is hash each pair, then make a table of the hashes. You also want (x,y)
to hash the same as (y,x).

```
R>data
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 face  1  4  6  7
2 face  2  7  6  8
3 face  3  9 11 12
4 face  4 10  9 12
R>e1 <- pmin(data[3],  data[4]) + pmax(data[3], data[4])/100
R>e2 <- pmin(data[3],  data[5]) + pmax(data[3], data[5])/100
R>e3 <- pmin(data[4],  data[5]) + pmax(data[4], data[5])/100
R>table(c(e1,e2,e3, recursive=TRUE))
 4.06  4.07  6.07  6.08  7.08   9.1  9.11  9.12 10.12 11.12
    1     1     2     1     1     1     1     2     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution. I might try another way, but I like the way you approached it!